# How to create WCF WebApi in standard ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, wcf-web-api

I want use WCF WebApi in a regular ASP.NET C# project.  Already I have created WCF WebApi in MVC application but I want to create in normal ASP.NET.   Are there any sample links to show this?

Comment: There are several flavors of WCF - which one are you talking about?  Are you looking for one that uses SOAP, or REST?  Please clarify your question as to what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi thank you for giving response.http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20HTTP i have fallow above link for webapi please check it once

Comment: So you want to do essentially the same thing in the tutorial, only using Web Forms instead of MVC?

Comment: yes Tim please give any link if you know ...

Comment: I couldn't find any with a quick Google search.  You could try it yourself (consider it a learning opportunity) :).  You also might want to take a look at [Introducing WCF WebHttp Services in .NET 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/01/06/introducing-wcf-webhttp-services-in-net-4.aspx) - it *might* be of value, though it's not the Web API.

Comment: If you run into specific issues, feel free to post questions - just show the code you have that isn't working and someone here should be able to give you an answer.  Good luck :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

File / New Project / ASP.NET Application

NuGet: Install-Package WebApi.All

Add a new ContactsResource

```
[ServiceContract]
public class ContactsResource {
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "")] 
    public List<Contact> Get() {
        return new List<Contact>()
                {
                    new Contact()
                        {
                            Name = "Alex"
                        }
                };
     }
}
```

Add a Contact class

```
public class Contact {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Edit the Global.asax.cs

Modify Application_Start:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // Code that runs on application startup
    RouteTable.Routes.MapServiceRoute<ContactsResource>("contacts");
}
```

Hit F5 and navigate to http://mywebsite/contacts

Done.

```
<ArrayOfContact>
    <Contact>
        <Name>Alex</Name>
    </Contact>
 </ArrayOfContact>
```